# No acceptable C compiler found in $PATH

Tags: macos, gcc

So here's the situation. I want to setup a portable programming environment by installing my programming stuff (Vim, Clang, Git, GCC) in a single folder that I can create on any Mac. I am installing everything in /opt, which isn't there by default and I should have write permissions to create. I got Vim, Clang, and Git working by downloading the Xcode Command Line Tools and a program that can extract the contents of the PKG's. I put everything in their respective folders in /opt, e.g /opt/usr/bin. They are all doing dandy.

Here's the problem. I am trying to get GCC to work. I downloaded the OSX GCC Installer and did the same technique with GCC-4.2. The problem is that when I do a test compile, I run this. **Edit: I get the same error message if I do CC=gcc-4.2**

```
./configure --prefix=/opt/usr/bin
```

and receive

```
checking build system type... x86_64-apple-darwin11.4.2
checking host system type... x86_64-apple-darwin11.4.2
checking target system type... x86_64-apple-darwin11.4.2
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether ln works... yes
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /usr/bin/sed
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... no
checking for nawk... no
checking for awk... awk
checking for libatomic support... yes
checking for libcilkrts support... yes
checking for libitm support... yes
checking for libsanitizer support... yes
checking for libvtv support... no
checking for gcc... no
checking for cc... no
checking for cl.exe... no
configure: error: in `/opt/gcc-master':
configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH
See `config.log' for more details.
```

This is strange because GCC-4.2 is in my $PATH

```
echo $PATH
/opt/usr/bin:/opt/usr/:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin

cd /opt/usr/bin ; ls | grep gcc
gcc
gcc-4.2
i686-apple-darwin11-gcc-4.2.1
```

FYI: 'gcc' is a symlink that doesn't point to anything.

```
which gcc-4.2
/opt/usr/bin/gcc-4.2
```

Comment: If you solved your problem, the correct approach on this site is to post an answer and to mark it as accepted.

Comment: Okay. I will do so now.

Answer (score 3):

I solved this by adding this to my .zshrc. It forces any configure script to look for gcc-4.2 instead of gcc.

```
CC=/opt/usr/bin/gcc-4.2
```

Answer (score 3):

configure: error: `no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH`
Before executing the ./configure command, i used the command:

`sudo apt install gcc`

And the error 'no acceptable ...' is solved.

Answer (score 0):

The gcc compiler is not in your $PATH. It means either you dont have gcc installed or it's not in your $PATH variable.

To install gcc use this: (run as root) for debian and derivatives

apt-get install build-essential

Comment: This answer appears to repeat information given already. Duplicate answers are not valid answers.